# Angular Universal add meta tag in subscription

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I am having some real issues trying to set meta tags dynamically.
I can easily set the tags in the **ngOnInit** method, but if I use a **Subscription** the addTag method does nothing.

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    public page: Page;
    public postSlug: string;

    private pages: Page[] = [];
    private url: string = '/';

    private routerSubscription: Subscription;
    private pagesSubscription: Subscription;

    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private contentfulService: ContentfulService,
        private pageService: PageService,
        private meta: Meta
    ) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.meta.addTag({ name: 'app', content: 'Set from app component' });
        this.url = this.router.url.split('#')[0]; // For initial page load

        this.contentfulService.getPages();
        this.getPages();
        this.onNavigationEnd();
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        if (this.routerSubscription) this.routerSubscription.unsubscribe();
        if (this.pagesSubscription) this.pagesSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }

    private onNavigationEnd(): void {
        this.routerSubscription = this.router.events.subscribe((event: any) => {
            if (!(event instanceof NavigationEnd)) return;

            this.url = event.urlAfterRedirects.split('#')[0];

            this.setPage();
            this.setPost();
        });
    }

    private setPost(): void {
        this.postSlug = undefined; // Always reset

        if (!this.page || this.url.indexOf('/live-better/') === -1) return;

        this.meta.addTag({ name: 'post', content: 'Set post' });

        var urlParts = this.url.split('/');
        this.postSlug = urlParts[urlParts.length - 1];
    }

    private setPage(): void {
        if (!this.pages.length || !this.url) return;
        this.page = this.pages.find((page: Page) => page.slug === this.url);

        if (!this.page) {
            this.page = this.pages.find(
                (page: Page) => this.url.indexOf(page.slug) === 0
            );
        }

        this.meta.addTag({ name: 'page', content: 'Set page' });

        console.log(this.page);

        this.pageService.setTitle(this.page.title);
        this.pageService.setMetadata(this.page);
    }

    private getPages(): void {
        this.pagesSubscription = this.contentfulService.pages.subscribe(
            (pages: Page[]) => {
                if (!pages.length) return;
                this.pages = pages;

                this.meta.addTag({ name: 'pages', content: 'Get pages' });

                this.setPage();
                this.setPost();
            }
        );
    }
}
```

The rest of the code executes and is fine. If I view source, I can see the tag for `{ name: 'app', content: 'Set from app component' }` but I can't see any of the others.

Does anyone know if there is something I am missing?

---

I figured this must be an issue with data loading after the view, so I created a resolver like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { ContentfulService } from '../services/contentful.service';
import { Meta } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { mergeMap, first } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable, of, from } from 'rxjs';

import { Resolve } from '../models/resolve';
import { Page } from '../models/page';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class PageResolver implements Resolve<{ page: Page; postSlug: string }> {
    constructor(
        private contentfulService: ContentfulService,
        private meta: Meta
    ) {}

    resolve(
        route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
        state: RouterStateSnapshot
    ): Observable<{ page: Page; postSlug: string }> {
        console.log('about to parse');
        return this.getData(state);
    }

    private getData(
        state: RouterStateSnapshot
    ): Observable<{ page: Page; postSlug: string }> {
        const currentUrl = state.url.split('#')[0];
        console.log(currentUrl);

        this.meta.addTag({ name: 'resolve', content: 'Resolving route' });
        if (!this.contentfulService.current.length) {
            console.log('first load');
            return from(
                this.contentfulService.getPages().then((pages: Page[]) => {
                    this.meta.addTag({
                        name: 'first',
                        content: 'First resolve hit',
                    });
                    return this.parseData(pages, currentUrl);
                })
            );
        } else {
            console.log('after load');
            return this.contentfulService.pages.pipe(
                first(),
                mergeMap((pages: Page[]) => {
                    this.meta.addTag({
                        name: 'second',
                        content: 'Changed page',
                    });
                    return of(this.parseData(pages, currentUrl));
                })
            );
        }
    }

    private parseData(
        pages: Page[],
        currentUrl: string
    ): { page: Page; postSlug: string } {
        let page = this.setPage(pages, currentUrl);
        let postSlug = this.setPost(page, currentUrl);
        let data: { page: Page; postSlug: string } = {
            page: page,
            postSlug: postSlug,
        };

        console.log(data);
        return data;
    }

    private setPage(pages: Page[], currentUrl: string): Page {
        if (!pages.length || !currentUrl) throw 'No pages have been loaded';
        let page = pages.find((page: Page) => page.slug === currentUrl);

        if (!page) {
            page = pages.find(
                (page: Page) => currentUrl.indexOf(page.slug) === 0
            );
        }

        return page;
    }

    private setPost(page: Page, currentUrl: string): string {
        if (!page || currentUrl.indexOf('/live-better/') === -1) return;

        let urlParts = currentUrl.split('/');
        let postSlug = urlParts[urlParts.length - 1];

        let queryIndex = postSlug.indexOf('?');
        if (queryIndex > -1) postSlug = postSlug.substring(0, queryIndex);

        return postSlug;
    }
}
```

and added it to my routing like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '**',
        component: HomeComponent,
        resolve: { content: PageResolver },
    },
];
```

Now in my **HomeComponent** I just get the data like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

import { Page } from '@models';
import { Meta } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
    selector: 'sxp-home',
    templateUrl: './home.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss'],
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
    public page: Page;
    public postSlug: string;

    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private meta: Meta) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.meta.addTag({ name: 'home', content: 'Home component loaded' });
        this.route.data.subscribe(
            (data: { content: { page: Page; postSlug: string } }) => {
                let content = data.content;
                this.meta.addTag({ name: 'meta', content: 'Subscription hit' });
                this.page = content.page;
                this.postSlug = content.postSlug;
                console.log(content);
            }
        );
    }
}
```

As you can see there, I have used `addTag` 3 times in the resolver and 2 times on the **HomeComponent**, but when I view source only one is actually added:

```
this.meta.addTag({ name: 'resolve', content: 'Resolving route' });
```

I just can't seem to set any meta tags behind any sort of subscription. I was hoping the resolver would delay the view page source from actually trying to get the data until everything had loaded in the resolver first.

I have added console logs after each `addTag` call.
You can view them here:

https://sxp-develop-marketing.azurewebsites.net/

Comment: No errors in the console server side? And when you view the source (CTRL+U), you do have the page content already rendered?

Comment: no console errors and yes I have the page content rendered

Comment: are you sure that your `this.contentfulService.pages` observable works? please add your code of that as well.

Comment: Yeah, the `console.log(page)` in the resolver is actually returning a page, so it get's that far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the reason metadata was not being set correctly was due to not using `TransferState`. I created a new service (TransferHttpService) which looks like this:

```
import { Injectable, Inject, PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import {
  TransferState,
  StateKey,
  makeStateKey,
} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Observable, from } from 'rxjs';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { isPlatformBrowser, isPlatformServer } from '@angular/common';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class TransferHttpService {
  constructor(
    protected transferState: TransferState,
    private httpClient: HttpClient,
    @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object
  ) {}

  request<T>(
    method: string,
    uri: string | Request,
    options?: {
      body?: any;
      headers?:
        | HttpHeaders
        | {
            [header: string]: string | string[];
          };
      reportProgress?: boolean;
      observe?: 'response';
      params?:
        | HttpParams
        | {
            [param: string]: string | string[];
          };
      responseType?: 'json';
      withCredentials?: boolean;
    }
  ): Observable<T> {
    // tslint:disable-next-line:no-shadowed-variable
    return this.getData<T>(
      method,
      uri,
      options,
      (method: string, url: string, options: any) => {
        return this.httpClient.request<T>(method, url, options);
      }
    );
  }

  /**
   * Performs a request with `get` http method.
   */
  get<T>(
    url: string,
    options?: {
      headers?:
        | HttpHeaders
        | {
            [header: string]: string | string[];
          };
      observe?: 'response';
      params?:
        | HttpParams
        | {
            [param: string]: string | string[];
          };
      reportProgress?: boolean;
      responseType?: 'json';
      withCredentials?: boolean;
    }
  ): Observable<T> {
    // tslint:disable-next-line:no-shadowed-variable
    return this.getData<T>(
      'get',
      url,
      options,
      (_method: string, url: string, options: any) => {
        return this.httpClient.get<T>(url, options);
      }
    );
  }

  /**
   * Performs a request with `post` http method.
   */
  post<T>(
    url: string,
    body: any,
    options?: {
      headers?:
        | HttpHeaders
        | {
            [header: string]: string | string[];
          };
      observe?: 'response';
      params?:
        | HttpParams
        | {
            [param: string]: string | string[];
          };
      reportProgress?: boolean;
      responseType?: 'json';
      withCredentials?: boolean;
    }
  ): Observable<T> {
    // tslint:disable-next-line:no-shadowed-variable
    return this.getPostData<T>(
      'post',
      url,
      body,
      options,
      // tslint:disable-next-line:no-shadowed-variable
      (_method: string, url: string, body: any, options: any) => {
        return this.httpClient.post<T>(url, body, options);
      }
    );
  }

  /**
   * Performs a request with `put` http method.
   */
  put<T>(
    url: string,
    _body: any,
    options?: {
      headers?:
        | HttpHeaders
        | {
            [header: string]: string | string[];
          };
      observe?: 'body';
      params?:
        | HttpParams
        | {
            [param: string]: string | string[];
          };
      reportProgress?: boolean;
      responseType?: 'json';
      withCredentials?: boolean;
    }
  ): Observable<T> {
    // tslint:disable-next-line:no-shadowed-variable
    return this.getPostData<T>(
      'put',
      url,
      _body,
      options,
      (_method: string, url: string, _body: any, options: any) => {
        return this.httpClient.put<T>(url, _body, options);
      }
    );
  }

  /**
   * Performs a request with `delete` http method.
   */
  delete<T>(
    url: string,
    options?: {
      headers?:
        | HttpHeaders
        | {
            [header: string]: string | string[];
          };
      observe?: 'response';
      params?:
        | HttpParams
        | {
            [param: string]: string | string[];
          };
      reportProgress?: boolean;
      responseType?: 'json';
      withCredentials?: boolean;
    }
  ): Observable<T> {
    // tslint:disable-next-line:no-shadowed-variable
    return this.getData<T>(
      'delete',
      url,
      options,
      (_method: string, url: string, options: any) => {
        return this.httpClient.delete<T>(url, options);
      }
    );
  }

  /**
   * Performs a request with `patch` http method.
   */
  patch<T>(
    url: string,
    body: any,
    options?: {
      headers?:
        | HttpHeaders
        | {
            [header: string]: string | string[];
          };
      observe?: 'response';
      params?:
        | HttpParams
        | {
            [param: string]: string | string[];
          };
      reportProgress?: boolean;
      responseType?: 'json';
      withCredentials?: boolean;
    }
  ): Observable<T> {
    // tslint:disable-next-line:no-shadowed-variable
    return this.getPostData<T>(
      'patch',
      url,
      body,
      options,
      // tslint:disable-next-line:no-shadowed-variable
      (
        _method: string,
        url: string,
        body: any,
        options: any
      ): Observable<any> => {
        return this.httpClient.patch<T>(url, body, options);
      }
    );
  }

  /**
   * Performs a request with `head` http method.
   */
  head<T>(
    url: string,
    options?: {
      headers?:
        | HttpHeaders
        | {
            [header: string]: string | string[];
          };
      observe?: 'response';
      params?:
        | HttpParams
        | {
            [param: string]: string | string[];
          };
      reportProgress?: boolean;
      responseType?: 'json';
      withCredentials?: boolean;
    }
  ): Observable<T> {
    // tslint:disable-next-line:no-shadowed-variable
    return this.getData<T>(
      'head',
      url,
      options,
      (_method: string, url: string, options: any) => {
        return this.httpClient.head<T>(url, options);
      }
    );
  }

  /**
   * Performs a request with `options` http method.
   */
  options<T>(
    url: string,
    options?: {
      headers?:
        | HttpHeaders
        | {
            [header: string]: string | string[];
          };
      observe?: 'response';
      params?:
        | HttpParams
        | {
            [param: string]: string | string[];
          };
      reportProgress?: boolean;
      responseType?: 'json';
      withCredentials?: boolean;
    }
  ): Observable<T> {
    // tslint:disable-next-line:no-shadowed-variable
    return this.getData<T>(
      'options',
      url,
      options,
      // tslint:disable-next-line:no-shadowed-variable
      (_method: string, url: string, options: any) => {
        return this.httpClient.options<T>(url, options);
      }
    );
  }

  // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
  getData<T>(
    method: string,
    uri: string | Request,
    options: any,
    callback: (
      method: string,
      uri: string | Request,
      options: any
    ) => Observable<any>
  ): Observable<T> {
    let url = uri;

    if (typeof uri !== 'string') {
      url = uri.url;
    }

    const tempKey = url + (options ? JSON.stringify(options) : '');
    const key = makeStateKey<T>(tempKey);
    try {
      return this.resolveData<T>(key);
    } catch (e) {
      //console.log('in catch', key);
      return callback(method, uri, options).pipe(
        tap((data: T) => {
          if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
            // Client only code.
            // nothing;
          }
          if (isPlatformServer(this.platformId)) {
            //console.log('set cache', key);
            this.setCache<T>(key, data);
          }
        })
      );
    }
  }

  private getPostData<T>(
    _method: string,
    uri: string | Request,
    body: any,
    options: any,
    callback: (
      method: string,
      uri: string | Request,
      body: any,
      options: any
    ) => Observable<any>
  ): Observable<T> {
    let url = uri;

    if (typeof uri !== 'string') {
      url = uri.url;
    }

    const tempKey =
      url +
      (body ? JSON.stringify(body) : '') +
      (options ? JSON.stringify(options) : '');
    const key = makeStateKey<T>(tempKey);

    try {
      return this.resolveData<T>(key);
    } catch (e) {
      return callback(_method, uri, body, options).pipe(
        tap((data: T) => {
          if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
            // Client only code.
            // nothing;
          }
          if (isPlatformServer(this.platformId)) {
            this.setCache<T>(key, data);
          }
        })
      );
    }
  }

  private resolveData<T>(key: StateKey<T>): Observable<T> {
    const data = this.getFromCache<T>(key);

    if (!data) {
      throw new Error();
    }

    if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
      //console.log('get cache', key);
      // Client only code.
      this.transferState.remove(key);
    }
    if (isPlatformServer(this.platformId)) {
      //console.log('we are the server');
      // Server only code.
    }

    return from(Promise.resolve<T>(data));
  }

  private setCache<T>(key: StateKey<T>, data: T): void {
    return this.transferState.set<T>(key, data);
  }

  private getFromCache<T>(key: StateKey<T>): T {
    return this.transferState.get<T>(key, null);
  }
}
```

And then I replaced any constructor that looked like this:

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
```

to this:

```
constructor(private http: TransferHttpService) {}
```

And then everything worked as it should

Answer (score 0):

The page source is static html and will be evaluated again when it is rendered on browser. The meta tags are inserted at that time.

To make them visible in page source, you must enable server side rendering -
https://angular.io/guide/universal

Comment: that's not true, the subscribe happens when a page changes, but `ngOnInit` invokes `getPages` which has `setPost()` in it.

Comment: it's correct the subscribe happend when a page changes, but only if you navigated to a child route.

Comment: can you please put console.log above each meta addition?

Comment: Will do; you helped me with my `PageResolver`. The reason I went down that route was to help with this issue

Comment: i know it :) so i wanted to see content service

Comment: I see :) I will post the url here in a second so you can see it live

Comment: I have added the console logs and uploaded them to the dev environment (link in my question)

Comment: only when inspecting; when view page source it only has one

Comment: i can understand, the page source is static html and will be evaluated again when it is rendered on browser. and your meta tags are inserted at that time.

Comment: What can I do to get the tags rendered ? I'm trying to set the title and description based on the page you are on

Comment: I should have made myself clear. I am already using angular universal (It says it in the title) :)

Comment: Yeah, that's the issue I am having

Comment: I think it might be something to do with https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-universal/ transfer api